# .htaccess remove .php extension not working with all pages

Tags: php, .htaccess

.htaccess file removes .php extension from URL. It works with two php pages, but it doesn't work with one. And there isn't any file with the same name.

Edit:

```
.htaccess file

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

My URL is now for example: website/contact.php, but I want to get rid of .php extension resulting this: webiste/contact. This .htaccess file works for 2 other pages.

Comment: show is your rules please

Comment: Please post the relevant contents of your .htaccess file, what your current URL structure is, and how you want it to display for the end user.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your pages in a sub folder. Thus `contact.php` becomes `/contact/index.php`... no rewrite rules needed.

Comment: I would like to use .htaccess method for contact.php to work like the other two pages. And if it won't work I will use your method.